# Ignoring the Null results in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, null, local-storage

I've a script using navigator's local storage valuesand i've developped a web service that sends me the values, the only issue here is that i dont need it to send me Null results, this is the Function:

```
 function SendNeedHelpLinkTrace() {

    var pLinkVirement = sessionStorage.getItem("pClickVirement");
    var pLinkCarteBancaire = sessionStorage.getItem("pLinkCarteBancaire");
    var pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom = sessionStorage.getItem("pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom");
    var pPaiementVignetteImpotTaxe = sessionStorage.getItem("PaiementVignetteImpotTaxe");
    var pLinkPaiementFactureEauElectricite = sessionStorage.getItem("pPaiementFactureEauElectricite");
    var pLinkServiceFatourati = sessionStorage.getItem("pCatchLinkServiceFatourati");
    var pLinkCihExpress = sessionStorage.getItem("pCatchLinkCihExpress");
    var pLinkEdocuments = sessionStorage.getItem("pCatchLinkEdocuments");


    var lChannelId = "01";
    var lServiceId = "900120";
    var lClientId = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenClientId.ClientID%>').value;

    alert(lClientId);
    var lData;
    var lCollect;

    console.log(lClientId);

        lData = pLinkVirement + " | " + pLinkCarteBancaire + " | " + pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom + " | " + pPaiementVignetteImpotTaxe + " | " + pLinkPaiementFactureEauElectricite + " | " + pLinkServiceFatourati + " | " + pLinkCihExpress + " | " + pLinkEdocuments;

        console.log(lData);

        alert(lData);

        lDataCollected = lClientId + ";" + lChannelId + ";" + lServiceId + ";" + lData;

        console.log(lDataCollected);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:9097/CatchEvent.asmx/CollectData",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "pData": lDataCollected }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus == "success") {
                    alert('success');
                }
            },
            error: function (exception) {
                alert('Exeption : ' + exception);
            }
        });
        sessionStorage.clear();

    }
```

the results are like this :

Null || 300123 || 900452 || Null || Null || 26332

what should i do to not show the Null results ?

Comment: Where are you getting Null data? in success?

Comment: no the function sends me the values stored in the local session so if it's a null value it'll send it in the data  lData = pLinkVirement + " | " + pLinkCarteBancaire + " | " + pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom + " | " + pPaie......

Comment: Can you show us a console log result of the variable `lDataCollected`? Which is the variable you want to send without `null` values.. Correct?

Comment: Have you heard about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object) and [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)? If no, now it's time to learn.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero the console result : Null || 300123 || 900452 || Null || Null || 26332

Comment: But is that an array or string? Can you show what you see in console?

Comment: it's String @YosvelQuintero

Comment: @anass90 so you want to skip it or just add a default blank (`''`) value.

Comment: @Rajesh Skipping it will be fine

Comment: @anass90 is `Null || 300123 || 900452 || Null || Null || 26332` and `300123 || 900452|| 26332` same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @[hindmost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118955/hindmost), you should create an array of keys that you need to send and loop through them.

But my personal recommendation, send object instead. This way you will know what is empty and what is not.

#### Sample Code

```js
// map of keys to fetch
var keysToSend = [
    'pClickVirement'
    'pLinkCarteBancaire'
    'pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom'
    'PaiementVignetteImpotTaxe'
    'pPaiementFactureEauElectricite'
    'pCatchLinkServiceFatourati'
    'pCatchLinkCihExpress'
    'pCatchLinkEdocuments'
]

// Loop to concatinate
var data = keysToSend.reduce(function(p,c){
  var _t = sessionStorage.getItem(c);
  return isEmpty(_t) ? p : p + ' | ' + _t;
}, '')

// Check validity
function isEmpty(val){
  return val === undefined || val === null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that `lDataCollected` is an string you can convert it to an array using [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and easily make a [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) excluding the 'Null' values from the array and finally [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to make an string again:

```js
var lDataCollected = 'Null || 300123 || 900452 || Null || Null || 26332';
var result = lDataCollected
  .split(' || ')
  .filter(function(item) {
    return item !== 'Null';
  })
  .join(' || ');

console.log(result);
```

Than, the final solution:

```
function SendNeedHelpLinkTrace() {
    var pLinkVirement = sessionStorage.getItem('pClickVirement'),
        pLinkCarteBancaire = sessionStorage.getItem('pLinkCarteBancaire'),
        pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom = sessionStorage.getItem('pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom'),
        pPaiementVignetteImpotTaxe = sessionStorage.getItem('PaiementVignetteImpotTaxe'),
        pLinkPaiementFactureEauElectricite = sessionStorage.getItem('pPaiementFactureEauElectricite'),
        pLinkServiceFatourati = sessionStorage.getItem('pCatchLinkServiceFatourati'),
        pLinkCihExpress = sessionStorage.getItem('pCatchLinkCihExpress'),
        pLinkEdocuments = sessionStorage.getItem('pCatchLinkEdocuments'),

        lChannelId = '01',
        lServiceId = '900120',
        lClientId = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenClientId.ClientID%>').value,
        lData = pLinkVirement + ' | ' + pLinkCarteBancaire + ' | ' + pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom + ' | ' + pPaiementVignetteImpotTaxe + ' | ' + pLinkPaiementFactureEauElectricite + ' | ' + pLinkServiceFatourati + ' | ' + pLinkCihExpress + ' | ' + pLinkEdocuments,
        lDataCollectedString = lClientId + ';' + lChannelId + ';' + lServiceId + ';' + lData,
        getLDataCollected = function(str) {
            var str
                .split(' || ')
                .filter(function(item) {
                    return item !== 'Null';
                })
                .join(' || ');
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'http://localhost:9097/CatchEvent.asmx/CollectData',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'pData': getLDataCollected(lDataCollectedString)
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus === 'success') {
                alert('success');
            }
        },
        error: function(exception) {
            alert('Exeption:' + exception);
        }
    });

    sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an **OR** check

Assuming `lData = pLinkVirement + " | " + pLinkCarteBancaire + " | " + pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom` produces **Null || 300123 || 900452**

Since you're getting the data from sessionStorage, the data will be stored as String, hence do a `JSON.parse` and do the following

**NOTE:**(incase the string is Null , then do `String.toLowerCase()` before `JSON.parse()`)

`lData = (pLinkVirement || '') + " | " + (pLinkCarteBancaire || '') + " | " + (pLinkRechargePaiementFactureTelecom || '')`

Say you got the data pLinkVirement from sessionStorage as Null, do the following

```
pLinkVirement = pLinkVirement.toLowerCase()
pLinkVirement = JSON.parse(pLinkVirement)
pLinkVirement = (pLinkVirement || '')
```

Comment: it's gave me an error cannot apply toLowerCase of Null !!

Comment: can u show me the code, where you're getting the above error? Also do note that to apply toLowerCase() method, the variable must be a string